# Should -fsanitize=address go into CFLAGS or LDFLAGS?

Tags: address-sanitizer, sanitizer

I'm trying to use address sanitizer using (`-fsanitize=address`) and I'm not sure if it belongs into CFLAGS or LDFLAGS. It actually seems to work fine when added just to LDFLAGS, but I do not know if that is a coincidence or if it is supposed to be like that.

Is `-fsanitize=address` needed for the compilation itself, or does it suffice to provide the flag for the linking step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is -fsanitize=address needed for the compilation itself, or does it suffice to provide the flag for the linking step?

Address Sanitizer instruments *source code* to insert additional checks, and so must be present at compilation time.

Providing the argument only on the link line results in asan *runtime* being linked into the process, but no checks being actually done, except for a small subset -- namely the checks achievable by interposing `new` `delete`, `malloc`, `free`, and other standard functions.

Example:

```
     1  #include <malloc.h>
     2  #include <stdio.h>
     3
     4  void fn(int *ip)
     5  {
     6    ip[0] = 1;  // BUG: heap buffer overflow
     7  }
     8
     9  int main()
    10  {
    11    int *ip = malloc(1);   // Allocation too small.
    12    printf("%d\n", ip[0]); // BUG: heap buffer overflow
    13    free(ip);
    14    free(ip);  // BUG: double free
    15  }
```

With no instrumentation, only the double-free is detected:

```
gcc -g -c t.c && gcc -fsanitize=address t.o && ./a.out
190
=================================================================
==55787==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting double-free on 0x602000000010 in thread T0:
```

With instrumentation: both the bug in `printf` and the bug in `fn` are also detected.

```
gcc -g -c -fsanitize=address t.c && gcc -fsanitize=address t.o && ./a.out
=================================================================
==58202==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x602000000010 at pc 0x564565639252 bp 0x7ffe36b0a560 sp 0x7ffe36b0a558
READ of size 4 at 0x602000000010 thread T0
    #0 0x564565639251 in main /tmp/t.c:12
```

Comment: That does not seem to be the case https://paste.vpsfree.cz/2J8aT4Ni/ . It correctly detects the double free it seems.